# Use hex colors instead of color presets

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-8.5

How can I change the report background color to a custom color in Crystal Reports 7? I don't want to use the color presets:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the color popup appears, simply click the "More..." text to open the color picker.

[image]

[image]

You can also define the colors by clicking the formula section (the blue x+2 button) and entering the color code via RGB:

```
 Color (255, 112, 36)
```

Comment: Thanks... It fixs my problem.